# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49152 bytes)

Tags: magento

magemnto after theme setup install theme then all product list page display properly buit when click on adddtocart button also view product detail page then error occerence like below

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49152 bytes)
in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php on line 289
```

[link](http://synctpl.com/erxpharmacy/index.php/body-care/alka-seltzer-original-effervescent-tablets-72-count.html)

Comment: Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862269/how-can-i-solve-magento-out-of-memory-fatal-error/36970041#36970041 You should increase your memory limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this normal Magento memory behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850836/is-this-normal-magento-memory-behaviour) Your php memory limit is set to 32M which is far short of the 256M or 512M that it will require to run.

Comment: Did the comments/answers solve your issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the value of "memory_limit" in your php.ini file ? Try something like 1024M.

Be careful, you could have several files named php.ini. If it doesn't work with the first one, thy another.